# App distribution through website ...?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have seen that few web sites , give an ipa and that ipa install to any iPhone device .. how it is possible Is there any way that my ipa could install to any iPhone device . without app store ?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/abPlayer_iPhone/abPlayer_ipa.zip
How it is possible? Any help ?

it is distributed publicly ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use over the air distribution for your app by uploading it to a website and accessing it via a specially crafted URL, similar to `itms://path/to/manifest.xml`. An example manifest file [can be found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Note though, that using this method without an enterprise distribution profile, you will still need to provision the devices that you expect to run the app on. You are limited to 100 devices on a normal developer account.

You can apply for an Enterprise account, if you need to distribute to more than 100 devices and you will not need to explicitly provision those devices. However, the terms of the Enterprise agreement state that it is to be used for in-house distribution only, not to the general public. If Apple find out that you are just using the enterprise distribution to get around the App Store, they will close the account. They may not even give you one in the first place, if you cannot prove that you will only use it for in-house distribution/testing.

Comment: I am a product maker and i want to give it to only my clients as add on feature.so what is the solution for it ? if iUse login / password then Apple reject the App. Any favorable solution ?

Comment: The solution is to apply for an Enterprise account, explaining your situation and how you intend to distribute the app (and who to), and hope that Apple approve your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload your ipa on testflightapp.com. they will provide you the link for download

Comment: You can do this, but remember you still need to provision the devices the app will run on in the iOS provisioning portal. You are limited to 100 devices. The only way you can get the app to run on any device un-provisioned is to use an Enterprise distribution profile. You will need to apply for an enterprise account from Apple - which, if you're not an enterprise, you will be unlikely to get.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to register with apple for [Enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), once you register, you can distribute the application without app store, with the distribution certificate.

Comment: The terms of the enterprise agreement state that the app can only be distributed in-house. Enterprise accounts don't give people free reign to distribute their app to the public outside of the app store. The enterprise account will be closed if Apple find out this is what is being done.